# Linear combinations of nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is meant to be a trivial question in a book that I'm reading, but after banging my head against it for some time and searching online I haven't found a solution.

Question: given a ring $R$ and two nilpotent elements $x$ and $y$, prove that for any $a,b \in R$ the element $ax + by$ is nilpotent. Hint: use the binomial expansion.

I'm having no trouble showing that $x+y$ is nilpotent, but when including the "coefficients" I'm having some trouble. I started by letting $n$ and $m$ be such that $x^n=0$ and $y^m=0$, and letting $k=\max\{n,m\}$. Then applying the binomial theorem gives:

$$ (ax+by)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \;(ax)^i \;(by)^{k-i} $$

If multiplication were commutative then this would be easy, as multiplication isn't necessarily commutative in a ring, I don't really know what to do. Both suggestions and complete answers are appreciated.

Comment: This is not true if multiplication is not required to be commutative. There are tautological counterexamples around like $\mathbb Q\left<x,y\right> / \left(x^n, y^n\right)$.

Comment: Also, in the commutative case, $k=\max\left\{n,m\right\}$ is not enough. What is enough is $k = n+m-1$ (or $0$ if $n=m=0$). If you are not sure why, try to write up the proof in more detail.

Comment: And also note that in applying the binomial theorem as you did you have already assumed commutativity. So your book is either wrong or it is talking about commutative rings.

Comment: Durp, sorry. The book definitely specifies that ring is commutative, I just missed. If one of you posts your comment as an answer (and perhaps finished the problem, for good measure) I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: Regarding the first comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation $\mathbb{Q}\langle x,y\rangle$ and $(x^n,y^n)$ - what are these objects? If you just give them names then I'm happy to look them up myself.

Comment: @alexvas By $\Bbb{Q}\langle  x,y\rangle$ I suppose Darij means the free algebra on the symbols $x,y$.

Answer (score 2):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As discovered in the comments, the user simply overlooked the requirement of commutativity, and in other comments learned how things can go wrong.

I am also going to point out that if the coefficients are distracting, then one can just prove independently that $xr$ and $x+y$ are nilpotent if $x,y$ are, and then the claim about linear combinations follows.

Answer (score -3):

In general, if R is semicommutative then the set nil(R) of all nilpotent elements of R forms an ideal, so the result follows.

Comment: The problem as stated above is clearly equivalent to proving that nil(R) is an ideal.